# M2: How to get storeId in javascript?

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, requirejs, store-id

I'am adding a new validation rule.

The result should depend on storeview code.

How can I get the storeId in the following javascript code?

**validator-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (validator) {

        validator.addRule(
            'validate-myrule',
            function (value, params) {

                //my rule logic which needs to know storeId

            },
            $.mage.__("rule error message")
        );

        return validator;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the window.checkout to get the websiteId
[image]

Comment: the websiteId is not storeviewId. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It looks like `window.checkout.storeId` is now available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use website id in js for conditions

```
var websiteId = window.checkout.websiteId;
```

Comment: the websiteId is not storeviewId. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, This works on the checkout page.

```
window.checkoutConfig.storeCode
```